# How to construct a custom const_iterator with const data?

Tags: c++

I'm writing the iterator classes for a custom container (some hash map class), let's call this container `Map`.

For a couple of reasons it seems handy to derive `iterator` from `const_iterator` and I already did this in some other custom container (an array class), which works great, so I want to stick to this pattern.

But now that leads to the following problem (which is quite general/abstract, I'm sorry):

Whatever `const_iterator`'s critical data member is (it might be a `Map` reference, or a pointer to `Map::Elements`, many ways are possible), **it needs to be non-const** so both `const_iterator` and the derived `iterator` can utilize it meaningfully in their methods.

But how can this non-const data member, in a proper way, be initialized when dealing with a const `Map` object (e.g. calling the method `const_iterator Map::Begin( void ) const`)?

---

To illustrate my question bit, I wrote some example code that solves the problem by using const_cast which, I suppose, is bad style:

```
#include <vector>

template< typename K, typename T >
class Map
{
public:
    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        const_iterator( Map const & a_Map, int a_Index ) : 
            m_Index( a_Index ),
            m_Map( const_cast< Map & >( a_Map ) )  // Note the use of const_cast
        {
        }
    private:
        Map & m_Map;
        int   m_Index;
    };
    class iterator : public const_iterator
    {
    public:
        T & operator * ( void )
        {
            return m_Map.mElements[ m_Index ];
        }
    };
public:
    const_iterator Begin( void ) const { return const_iterator( *this, 0 ); }
    iterator       Begin( void )       { return       iterator( *this, 0 ); }
private:
    std::vector< T > m_Elements;
};
```

Comment: Typical iterators don't actually contain your so-called "critical data member" at all. There is usually no connection between a real-life (release) iterator and the container to which it refers.

Comment: I know this is probably for academic curiosity but there is a `std::map` which will probably perform better than a `std::vector` being wrapped into a custom map.

Comment: @Kerrek SB You're absolutely right. Anyway this is just an example, the "critical data member" could be anything (for example a pointer to the first Element in `m_Elements` of the Map that provided the iterator). Whatever approach I use the problem is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I played with this in the past, I convinced myself that inheritance wasn't a good idea. While `iterator` and `const_iterator` might share a lot of code, they don't really share much in their interface.

Instead, I used templates to get the code reuse, so that `iterator` and `const_iterator` are just two versions of the same template. Provide an appropriate implicit conversion operator.

But if you insist on the inheritance model, and don't want your iterator to have its own non-const reference (i.e. its constructor initializes both its non-const version and the base class's const version), then `const_cast` is the only real option, I think.

Comment: Thanks! So if const_cast is the only option (besides abandoning inheritance) I can live with it.

Comment: As an aside, you probably want a pointer member, not a reference member. Think about what it means to have something of type `const iterator`. e.g. how `int *const` behaves.

Comment: As another aside, I wanted to make sure you're aware of the consequences of doing this sort of thing. It may be confusing for others to read your code (or for *you* to read your code 6 months later). It can defeat optimizations made by the container to make the `const` version faster than the non-`const` version. It may also prevent the compiler from doing optimizations as well.

Comment: What sort of thing do you mean, what's confusing with it and why can it defeat optimizations?

Comment: I once doubled the performance of a computationally-intensive routine just by getting it fully `const` correct. Yes, that's a rather extreme case, but it does demonstrate that it does help the compiler out. Also, source code-level optimizations can show up too -- e.g. the const version of `dynamic_bitset::operator[]` (or the C++98 `vector<bool>`) is much simpler than the non-const version. One could imagine containers with more significant overhead needed for the non-const version!